# RPGMakerVX - Changing item_max?

Tags: software-engineering

I've been working on a game for awhile and I am developing it with RPG Maker VX. I came to a point where I needed to... I guess for lack of better explanation... Limit the key items to just 1. So I started looking through my scripts and found (in Game_Party):

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Get Maximum Number of Items Possessed
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def max_item_number(item)
    return 99
  end
```

and added below it:

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Get Maximum Number of Key Items Possessed
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def max_key_item_number(item)
    return 1
  end
```

and right below that is:

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Determine if Maximum Number of Items Are Possessed
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def item_max?(item)
    item_number(item) >= max_item_number(item)
  end
```

So I changed the last one too:

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Determine if Maximum Number of Items Are Possessed
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def item_max?(item)
    if key_item? == true
      item_number(item) >= max_key_item_number(item)
    end

    if key_item? == false
      item_number(item) >= max_item_number(item)
    end
  end
```

Now this seemed to not affect anything (that I could tell). I tested it and its still the same as before I touched anything. I am new to developing games and relatively new to scripting for them. Is this approach even close to what I want to do? Any help is greatly apprecieated!

Comment: You'll probably have more luck over at the official RPG Maker forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it. Figured it out after playing around for about 2 hours lol.

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Determine if Maximum Number of Items Are Possessed
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def item_max?(item)
    if item.key_item?
      item_number(item) >= max_key_item_number(item)
    else
      item_number(item) >= max_item_number(item)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Mark your answer as correct when you get the chance. :)